# Migrating from 18.04 to 20.04 => very slow boot, ANY application starts very slowly

Tags: boot

I have a lenovo x220 which has ran on all ubuntu versions since 2011. The latest installed was 18.04 which ran smoothly. I decided to upgrade today (why...?) and followed the instructions to upgrade to 20.04.

Booting takes a good 4 to 5 min and any program I start takes for ever to launch. A terminal window takes about 15 seconds to launch. Firefox or Chromium or LibreOffice take over one minute.

I ran systemd-analyze:

```
1min 2.599s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
 1min 411ms vboxdrv.service                                                                          
    44.162s mysql.service                                                                            
    24.989s snapd.service                                                                            
    23.539s networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
    18.152s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
    17.243s php7.4-fpm.service                                                                       
    17.030s php7.2-fpm.service                                                                       
    14.429s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device                                               
    12.992s systemd-journal-flush.service                                                            
    11.769s teamviewerd.service                                                                      
    11.262s udisks2.service                                                                          
    10.261s accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
     9.941s NetworkManager.service                                                                   
     9.934s nginx.service                                                                            
     8.555s ModemManager.service                                                                     
     8.491s polkit.service                                                                           
     8.030s dev-loop22.device                                                                        
     7.705s dev-loop8.device                                                                         
     7.703s dev-loop13.device                                                                        
     7.701s dev-loop15.device                                                                        
     7.700s dev-loop16.device                                                                        
     7.644s dev-loop18.device                                                                        
     7.402s gpu-manager.service                                                                      
     7.401s dev-loop19.device                                                                        
     7.216s dev-loop24.device                                                                        
     7.174s dev-loop23.device                                                                        
     6.970s avahi-daemon.service                                                                     
     6.969s bluetooth.service                                                                        
     6.361s switcheroo-control.service                                                               
     6.355s thermald.service                                                                         
     6.349s systemd-logind.service
```

I removed virtualbox and php7.2-fpm , I dont understand why mysql would take 44s to start.

Please let me know what could be done to recover a decent boot time and a decent launch time for programs.

Thanks